# I am looking for a way to have gulp watch for a json of directories

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

```
var paths = {
    css: "css/**/*.{scss,sass}",
    js: "js/**/*.js",
    other: ["fonts/**/*.ttf", "images/**/*.{gif,png,jpg}", "includes/**"]
}
```

I can run

```
gulp.watch(paths.css, css); //compile sass and copy to template directory
gulp.watch(paths.js, js); //compile js and copy to template directory
gulp.watch(paths.other, copy_other); //when something changes in these, copy to template output directory
```

But that doesn't remove deleted files from the template output directory. When I remove lets say js/test.js it just compiles all js and copies them to output but doesn't remove test.js from template output directory.
I want to have an additional watch thread looking for deleted files in every path of the given path json object

```
gulp.watch(paths).on("unlink", function(path) {
        delete(path);
     }); //delete() takes filename and deletes it in template output directory
```

Doesn't work because watch expects a string not a json object:

```
TypeError: expected a string
```

Just using cwd()+"/**" complains about too many files.

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached...
```

Comment: Per "Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached..." have tried increasing the ulimit on the server?

Comment: No, that would be no solution because I can't increase the limit on the server each time a file is added. I wanted to have gulp.watch watching on all directories specified in the json and only these... There must be a way to do that.

Comment: If you convert the paths object to an array like const pathsArray = Object.values(paths); does it complain about too many files?  Also, the third item in the resultant array is itself an array and I don't know if gulp/chokidar will accept that.  In which case you would have to decompose that into its separate parts.

Comment: To flatten the json object: const pathsArray = Object.values(paths);

const flatPaths = pathsArray.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);  if you are not using node v11.  If you are on node v11 just use const pathsArray = Object.values(paths);
const flatPaths = pathsArray.flat();

Comment: Cool that should do it

Comment: Did flattening the json object to an array fix your problem?